# PL/SQL query to solve

Tags: plsql

Which of the following are correct PL/SQL syntaxes for a strong ref cursor?

```
a> TYPE MyRefCur IS STRONG REF CURSOR.    
b> TYPE MyRefCur IS REF CURSOR.    
c> TYPE MyRefCur IS STRONG REF CURSOR RETURN emp%ROWTYE.   
d> TYPE MyRefCur IS STRONG REF CURSOR STRONG.    
e> TYPE MyRefCur IS REF CURSOR emp%ROWTYPE.
```

Comment: Are you in an exam? Check this site on how to use this forum: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: None of them are correct. PL/SQL statements are terminated by semicolons, not periods.

Comment: @trinimon: well, at least he wasn't looking at someone else's exam... :-)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above are correct as none of them provide the correct syntax for a "strong" ref cursor. The correct way to declare a REF CURSOR which returns a specific row type is:

```
TYPE STRONG_REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR RETURN SOME_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
```

Other structures can be returned besides a %ROWTYPE - see the references [here (12c)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS568), [here (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS503), [here (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#i7106), and [here (10.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_variables.htm).

Share and enjoy.